# Optimization using Quadratic form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How do I find the maximum value of $$x^2+xy+2y^2$$ subject to the constraint $x^2+3y^2=16$?

Comment: Sooner or later someone will ask: "What have tried?"

Comment: Ever heard of Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 3):

The [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) are absolutely perfect for this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using quadratic form:
HINT: $ x^TAx = \begin{bmatrix}x & y \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 16 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{3}{16} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then diagonalize $A$ and solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: great! I like this method, but how did you get 3/2 and 9/16

Comment: @jaredsmith You want to make the constraint in standard form. i.e. $ax^2 + bx^2 = 1$ So take a look at $x^2 + 3y^2 = 16$. To change that to standard form, just divide by 16. You'll get $(\frac{x}{4})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{3}y}{4})^2 = 1$ and set new variables to make the equation less complicated.

Comment: are you sure thats right?,because I plug it in and get something else

Comment: I get  x_1 =4x, y_1= 4y/Sqrt[3] then I get 16x^2+(4x)(4y/Sqrt[3])+2*(4y/sqrt[3])^2